# mysql query returning the same row multiple times

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having a difficult time figuring out why my mysql query is returning the same row five times.  Here is the query below.  I read on here something about joins and cartisian products.  I'm very new to this, and editing this query on my site that someone else initially created.  Trying to understand the joins that are used here, but it's confusing me.  Any help is greatly appreciated.  The goal is to get each row to return only once, not five times.  Thanks!

```
SELECT off . * , resp.tracking_date, resp.paid_date, resp.total_value, resp.total_conversion
FROM tbl_offers AS off, tbl_tracking AS tr, tbl_trackvalue AS resp, tbloffers_cat AS offcat
WHERE off.id = tr.offer_id
AND off.offer_type = 'cash_offer'
AND off.id = offcat.offer_id
AND tr.id = resp.tracking_id
AND tr.user_id = '1454'
AND resp.total_value !=0
AND resp.payment_status = 'paid'
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Wow, thanks for all the help everyone.  Looks like a lot of the solutions mentioned here would work.  I did get the result I want by adding a group by tracking_id to the query.  Not sure if that's actually the best way to do it or not.  I'm just learning to program while editing an old site, which I initially had someone else build.  Lot's of fun.  The whole join thing is one of the more complicated things I've dealt with so far, but I'm sure it'll get easier.

I'll go through these answers to pick the best one, though it looks like multiple could work, so I'm not sure what the standard method of picking is on this site.  Thanks again!

Comment: Its working properly.Try using DISTINCT keyword.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like tbloffers_cat is used in the query, and may contain rows that aren't visible in your result set.  To verify this, add `tbloffers_cat.*` to your query and see if the values in those fields differ from row to row.

If that's the case, try this:

```
SELECT off.*
    , resp.tracking_date
    , resp.paid_date
    , resp.total_value
    , resp.total_conversion
FROM tbl_offers AS off
    INNER JOIN tbl_tracking AS tr ON tr.offer_id = off.id
    INNER JOIN tbl_trackvalue AS resp ON resp.tracking_id = tr.id
WHERE off.offer_type = 'cash_offer'
AND tr.user_id = '1454'
AND resp.total_value !=0
AND resp.payment_status = 'paid'
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

In  my opinion, The syntax of inner joins is usually clearer when looking at the query.

Comment: While everyone was helpful, yours got me the results I need without adding my group by workaround.  All the other answers still returned multiple rows.  Still don't fully understand why it works, but now I can dig into your solution to understand the differences.  Thanks.

Comment: Looks like it has to do with inner join vs. left join.  Inner join is getting me only the results I need, whereas left join was returning multiple rows for the same data.

Comment: Without seeing the entire schema of the tables, the best I can tell you is that there must have been multiple rows in the tbloffers_cat table that match more than one record when you're looking just at tbloffers_cat.offer_id.  I have a hunch that those tables actually match on different criteria.

Comment: Any chance the offer_id is null in the tbl_offers table?

Comment: You were correct that tbloffers_cat has an id column that differs between each of the returned rows.  This wasn't showing before I added it to the select.  Why would it take that into account though considering the original query doesn't mention the offcat.id at all?  It mentions offcat.offer_id = off.id (those two always did match in each row).  So why would it matter when none of the mentioned columns in offcat were different?  Thanks again for the help.

Comment: the offcat id column wasn't NULL, but the numbers differ for each of the returned rows. Trying to understand why that has an effect.

Comment: Look at this way:  let's say offcat.offer_id = 5.  If you select * from offcat where offer_id = 5, let's say you get 3 rows, each with a different value for offcat.id.  That means for every row in offers that has an id of 5, that row will appear 3 times in your result set if you join to the offcat table on offcat.offer_id = off.id.

Comment: It's starting to click now.  I'm thinking it's because there were multiple rows within offcat table that matched the WHERE off.id = offcat.offer_id.  Since there were multiple rows in offcat where the id column differed but the offer_id column remained the same,  the query pulled in all those rows since they match the off.id.  Phew!  Thanks again.  This is fun.

Comment: Perfect, we just described similar things, so I must be starting to get it.  I'm sure I'll have to bang up against this a few more times before it really cements itself.  Really helpful responses, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

While your query should be working as intended, it's using deprecated syntax, I suggest replacing the deprecated implicit joins with standard explicit joins:

```
SELECT off. * , resp.tracking_date, resp.paid_date, resp.total_value, resp.total_conversion
FROM tbl_offers AS off
JOIN tbl_tracking AS tr
 ON off.id = tr.offer_id
JOIN tbl_trackvalue AS resp
 ON tr.id = resp.tracking_id
JOIN tbloffers_cat AS offcat
 ON off.id = offcat.offer_id
WHERE off.offer_type = 'cash_offer'
  AND tr.user_id = '1454'
  AND resp.total_value !=0
  AND resp.payment_status = 'paid'
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

As to the multiple records, if the `JOIN` criteria doesn't identify a one to one relationship then you'll get multiple rows where you expected 1.  Try selecting fields from all tables in your query to see which table has multiple values being returned. Perhaps there are multiple tracking records with the same offer_id, but you wouldn't see that in your query because you aren't selecting anything from the tracking table.

Comment: When you use this syntax what type of join is being performed?

Comment: @user2616350 `JOIN` = `INNER JOIN`, `LEFT JOIN` = `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, `RIGHT JOIN` = `RIGHT OUTER JOIN`

Answer (score 0):

You have a [cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) in your query.

You should JOIN tbl_offers and all other table like this

FROM tbl_offers a JOIN tbl_tracking  u ON a.id = u.offer_id

So try like this

```
SELECT off. * , resp.tracking_date, resp.paid_date, resp.total_value, resp.total_conversion
FROM tbl_offers AS off
JOIN tbl_tracking AS tr
 ON off.id = tr.offer_id
JOIN tbl_trackvalue AS resp
 ON tr.id = resp.tracking_id
JOIN tbloffers_cat AS offcat
 ON off.id = offcat.offer_id
WHERE off.offer_type = 'cash_offer'
  AND tr.user_id = '1454'
  AND resp.total_value !=0
  AND resp.payment_status = 'paid'
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Read more about joining tables here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/join.html

Comment: While I agree that explicit joins should be used, the OP's query does define the joins in the where criteria.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the best solution, but I am now getting the result I want by adding:  group by tracking_id to the query.  I'm still learning while updating my site, so I'm sure I'll learn more about why that worked as I continue.

Answer (score 0):

***SQL JOINS***

Codeproject has this image which explains the simple basics of SQL joins, taken from:

[Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)

[image]

update your query as follows here

```
SELECT off.*,resp.tracking_date, resp.paid_date, resp.total_value, resp.total_conversion
FROM tbl_offers AS off
LEFT JOIN  tbl_tracking AS tr ON tr.offer_id = off.id
LEFT JOIN  tbl_trackvalue AS resp ON  resp.tracking_id = tr.id 
LEFT JOIN  tbloffers_cat AS offcat ON offcat.offer_id = off.id
WHERE  off.offer_type = 'cash_offer'
AND tr.user_id = '1454'
AND resp.total_value != 0
AND resp.payment_status = 'paid'
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

hope this will solve your problem